# Semantic category prediction of hierarchal data

Tags: mongodb, search, machine-learning, classification

I'm building a web app that services businesses of a few industries.
I want to build a Search box that simply asks

**What Type of Work Do You Do?**

|____Search Box_____|

The user can enter any text, and based on the keywords, I want to suggest some categories. Ideally, I want to return 5 results with their associated confidence levels and let them choose via checkboxes.

for Example, if

**Keyword: scrubbing**

**Results:**

- 0: [House Cleaning, 209]
- 1: [End of Lease Cleaning, 589]
- 2: [Office Cleaning, 210]
- 3: [Outdoor Cleaning, 202]
- 4: [General Gardening, 161]

or if **Keyword: auto wheel**

**Results:**

- 0: [Car Spray Painting, 533]
- 1: [Panel Beating, 104]
- 2: [Car Cleaning & Detailing, 96]
- 3: [Car Mechanics, 101]
- 4: [Automatic Doors & Gates, 185]

Where the number on the right is the confidence.

Notice that I am often using synonyms as keywords. Given that I have categories in a **MongoDB** document structured like so:

```
{
  'cleaning' : {
   'Outdoor Cleaning' : [ 'Outdoor', 'Yard', 'Cleaning', 'Field' ],
   'Office Cleaning' : ['Indoor', 'Office', 'Business', 'Corporate', Cleaning', 'Scrubbing']
  },
  'auto': {
    'mechanic' : ['car', '...']
  }
}
```

How can I return the desired result? 
I trained a **Naive Bayes** classifier but that only classifies into one category.
I am now looking into **Term Frequency–Inverse Document Frequency (tf-idf)** to get a set of ranked results but I am a little worried about my data model not fitting the algorithm.

Will I have to include every possible synonym to train the categories? Should I wait till it's live to manually train the categories based on real keyword searches?

I can still change my data model if someone knows of a better way to structure this information... If someone has experience with a problem such as this, any insight is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You have to train your classifier for all the categories, make training set and i recommend to use Elasticsearch or SOLR for ranking the results. And also you can store the user input in order to see what users commonly search for and use that information also for training you classifier.

Comment: Naive Bayes actually ranks the categories, so it can be used to output more than a single category (instead of taking just the category with maximal probability, sort by probability and take the top 5).